# How to resolve an error using apply to create a new column in pandas?

Tags: pandas, apply

I am trying to create a new column with a function who transform positions in strings Degrees minutes and simbol to position in number.
The column is:

> Latitud
> 45º27.19'N
> 45º17,4'N
> 46º18,8'N
> 45º19.54'N
> 45º32.47'N
> ....

```
   def formatear (x):
    deg, minutes, direction =  re.split('[º\']', x)
    valor = float(deg) + float(minutes.replace(",","."))/60  * (-1 if direction in ['W', 'S'] else 1)
    return valor
```

Apply function to create a new column

`df["LatitudDec"] = df["Latitud"].apply(formatear)`

when I apply the function the error is.

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Comment: I suspect this has nothing to do with `apply`, it is in your `re.split('[º\']', x)`. Please post the full backtrack.

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing the data as well as the code that produces your problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Comment: At least one element `x` of your `Latitud` column you're applying on does not split into exactly three strings which you're trying to catch via `deg, minutes, direction`. You need to enhance the implementation of your `formatear` function to handle unexpected/wrong situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not providing enough information to be properly answered, but here a little modification to track down the reason of the error:

```
def formatear (x):
    try:
        deg, minutes, direction =  re.split('[º\']', x)
        valor = float(deg) + float(minutes.replace(",","."))/60  * (-1 if direction in ['W', 'S'] else 1)
    except ValueError:
        print(f'There has been an error associated with the Latitud {x}')
        valor = np.nan
    return valor
```